# iOS QLPreviewController - show correct file name when saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, quicklook

I'm using QLPreviewController to handle file previews. Currently I set a customized file name using

```
@implementation WAFilePreviewItem

- (instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url displayName:(NSString *)displayName {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _previewItemURL = url;
        _previewItemTitle = displayName;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

the datasource set the previewItemTitle to be the desired format, and I'm getting it showing correctly on the preview. However when clicking on the save to folder button, it doesn't show the correct file name but the name extracted from file path. See below
[image]

Any idea how can I apply the correct file name even when clicking the save button?

Comment: I think you should change file name.

Comment: File a bug. In the meantime, rename your file (or if you can’t, clone it?)

Comment: @trungduc looks like changing file name is the only option?

Comment: @BruceXindaLin I think it’s a simple and possible option